# imacro for excel vba?

Tags: excel, imacros, vba

Need advice on how to use imacro in excel vba. imacro is the internet macro recoder found in internet explorer and firefox. Does anyone know how do you activate imacro using excel vba?

If you do know how to do this, kindly list down a sample code on how to activate imacro using excel vba.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Scripting#Connect_Excel_to_the_Web

Just FYI - activating iMacro via Excel is only available in the Enterprise (not free) version.  The trial version included in your initial download will allow you to using the scripting functionality for 30 days.